# C# e-mail issue

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I have this help desk application which sends an e-mail to me with a specific issue. The user is required to input his e-mail address into a textbox. What I'd like to do is for the user to get a copy of the problem as well.

```
MailMessage req_mail = new MailMessage(reqMail.Text, "system.admin@home.com");
```

Where reqMail.Text is the user's e-mail address.

Any ideas why it doesn't work? Because I can see from who it is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overload of the `MailMessage` constructor you're using takes a `from` and a `to` address.

You've supplied the users email as the `from` and your email as `to`. AFAIK, there isn't a constructor for CC'ing or BCC'ing.

Instead you just need to do this:

```
req_mail.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(reqMail.Text));
```

Or:

```
req_mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress(reqMail.Text));
```

If you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the constructor you're using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14k9fb7t(v=vs.110).aspx) that `MailMessage` is *from* the user, not *to* the user.  If you want to send the message *to* the user then their address would need to be in the `To` or `CC` or `BCC` parts of the message.  Something like:

```
var req_mail = new MailMessage(reqMail.Text, "system.admin@home.com");
req_mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress(reqMail.Text));
```